# How to view the original script of a materialized view?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, materialized

I am interested in moving a materialized view from one db to the other, regardless, I also need to change one of the columns. How can I view the original script that build the MV? I am running TOAD, but cannot seem to find the original script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the function `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'MVIEW_NAME') from dual;
```

Comment: Use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'VIEW', 'SCHEMA')` if you need to specify a different schema.

Answer (score 9):

I ended up running:

```
select * from all_mviews where mview_name = ‘YOUR_MV_NAME’;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select query from user_mviews
  where mview_name = 'your materialized view';
```

Comment: Note that this will only show you views that your user owns (USER_MVIEWS)

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) you just have to go to the "view" or "materialized view" node of the navigation tree